# RabbitMQ, EasyNetQ Queue Name

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

My Queue name is "TaskQueue" but when i run code, create new queue which name is "System_String:mscorlib_TaskQueue". My Subscriber code below. What is my fault?

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;username=guest;password=guest");
bus.SubscribeAsync<string>("TaskQueue", (msg) =>
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Got Message: {0}", msg);
    }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're doing it right. However, `TaskQueue` is the subscription id and *not* the name of the queue which gets generated.

By default EasyNetQ will use the subscription id *and* the type of the message for generating the name of the queue. Hence, it's named `System_String:mscorlib_TaskQueue` 
So all subscriptions with the id `TaskQueue` will be treated as concurrent consumers.

See https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Subscribe

You could change this behavior with [Taking Control Of The SubscriptionId Generation](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Auto-Subscriber)

Comment: @DawoodAwan fixed